# How to fix fwrite not writing to file in C?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, file-handling

I am trying to write a record to a file using the binary mode in C using `fwrite()` function, but the file remains empty however it is created and opened successfully.

I've already tried using different modes of opening the file.
I'm using the Turbo C3 compiler because of the technological constraints.

```
void Register () {
  FILE *User_File;
  User_File = fopen ("C://TURBOC3//SOURCE//USERDATA.DAT", "wb");
  active_user = _register_user();  //active user is of type struct _acc
  fwrite (&active_user, sizeof (struct _acc), 1, User_File);
  fclose (User_File);
}
```

Expected the data to be written in the file
File remains empty even after multiple tries

The structure `_acc` is as follows

```
struct _acc {
  char      *h_name;
  char       sex;
  struct date dob;
  char      *address;
  long int  mobile;
  int           pin;
  long int  accno; 
  double        account_bal;
  struct date acc_open_date;
  char       *username;
  char       *password;
  int           security_Q;  //used in case of forgot password
  char       *security_A;  //used in case of forgot password
  int       block_status;
};
typedef struct _acc acc;
```

The declaration of `_register_user()` is as follows:

```
acc _register_user ();
// This function returns a variable of type acc
```

Comment: "C://TURBOC3//SOURCE//USERDATA.DAT" is a strange path. Did you try "\\" instead of "//"? And did the `fopen()` work, i.e. did you check the returnvalue? Did you check against null pointer?

Comment: Does your version of fwrite set an error status?

Comment: regarding: `User_File = fopen ("C://TURBOC3//SOURCE//USERDATA.DAT", "wb");`  The code does not know if that statement was successful (or not)  Strongly suggest the next few statements be: `if( !User_file ) { perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: It is strongly recommended to NOT use leading underscore(s) in user names.  Specifically a `__` and a `_` followed by a capital letter are 'reserved' for the C environment

Comment: the posted code fails to check the returned value from the call to `fwrite()`  (it should be the same as the third parameter)  So how is the code to know if the call to `fwrite()` was successful (or not)?\

Comment: regarding the definition of `struct _acc`,  those fields that contain a pointer, to be written to the file, must be done by serialization of the data.  A rather error prone process,  Strongly recommend that those `char *` fields be redefined to something similar to:  `#define MAX_H_NAME_LEN 30` and `char h_name[ MAX_H_NAME_LEN ];`

Comment: regarding: `acc _register_user ();
// This function returns a variable of type acc`  This is a poor plan.  Strongly suggest the function malloc memory for a `struct _acc`, then fill in that struct, then return a pointer gotten from `malloc()`   And, of course, after writing the data, pass that pointer to `free()`.    Also, when calling `fopen()` the mode: "wb" always truncates the file,  Suggest using: "ab"`

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct _acc acc;`  it is considered 'normal' for `typedef'd and `#define'd names to be ALL CAPS

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Hi, your program might be missing the permissions to write to files.

Comment: What do you mean by "the file is empty"? Is its size 0? Or did you try to open the file with your editor and it showed nothing? Did you look into the file with a hex editor?

Comment: Opening or writing to a file can FAIL for all sorts of reasons.   Check the values returned by `fopen()` and `fwrite()` for error status.    Also .... your structure contains pointers, so using `fwrite()` will not write the pointed-to data to the file.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response, Regarding some questions: I used "WB" temporarily for the checking purpose, my program has all the needed permissions to rwx a file, i tried checking the `fwrite()` return value and it is not the same as the 3rd parameter, the file opens successfully (`fopen()` checked), the naming convention and `typedef` have been checked several times and are very much valid according to the TurboC compiler, and I'll try to use `malloc` in the `_register_acc()` method, the file is empty means it's storage size is 0 bytes.